# Creating checkboxgroup from extjs store

Tags: extjs

I want to create checkbox group from store populated from an array.
Here is my store.

```
var checklistStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        data: arraySubT,
        fields: ['id', 'boxLabel']
    });
```

and currently my checkbox group in only getting displayed from an array and not store.

```
                            xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                            fieldLabel: 'Checklist',
                            columns: 1,
                            vertical: true,
                            listeners: {
                                change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){

                                }
                            },
                            items: checkboxconfigs
```

However I want to make it displayed from store.How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to get a value from the store (boxLabel is probably just a label...) false: unchecked, true: checked. Which version of extjs do you use? Make a fiddle with your current working app. Someone could then modify it to get the config from a store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]
For your and my convenience, I made a general component which you can use. It may need some tuning regarding the store events that it reacts to. Find it in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1544).
[/EDIT]

You have to do it manually:

```
renderCheckboxes:function() {
    checkboxgroup.removeAll();
    checkboxgroup.add(
        checklistStore.getRange().map(function(storeItem) {
            return {
               // map the storeItem to a valid checkbox config
            }
        })
    );
}
```

and repeat that over and over and over again when the store data changes. That is, you have to attach to the store events:

```
checklistStore.on({
    load:renderCheckboxes,
    update:renderCheckboxes,
    datachanged:renderCheckboxes,
    filterchange:renderCheckboxes,
    ...
})
```

Maybe you will overlook some events you have to attach to, but sooner or later you will have all edge cases covered.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander.Need to know as how do I use the config for checkboxgroup : xtype: 'checkboxgroup', fieldLabel:'Checklist etc

Comment: I mean how will the checkboxes will display.Sorry but I am much new to extjs.How and where to call renderCheckboxes function.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for same.

Comment: Since it could come handy for me some time in the future, I made a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1544 After you have defined `xtype:'storecheckboxgroup'` using `Ext.define`, you can use it just like a normal checkboxgroup. It has two more required parameters, `mapFn` and `store`, but other than that, you can use all parameters that work on a normal checkboxgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/153l) for you.

Just loop through store data with [`Ext.data.Store.each()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each) method and setup your checkbox group items.

```
var _checboxGroupUpdated = function() {
    // Use whatever selector you want
    var myCheckboxGroup = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel checkboxgroup')[0];

    myCheckboxGroup.removeAll();
    myStore.each(function(record) {
        myCheckboxGroup.add({
            boxLabel: record.get('fieldLabel'),
            inputValue: record.get('value'),
            name: 'myGroup'
        });
    });
}

// Add all listeners you need here
myStore.on({
    load: _checboxGroupUpdated,
    update: _checboxGroupUpdated,
    datachanged: _checboxGroupUpdated
    // etc
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey.Will this work after adding an item dynamically to the store.After addition to store will it automatically display the new checkbox.

Comment: Add event listeners with `.on()` as @Alexander mentioned if you want it dinamically

Comment: @coolbuddy, I updated my fiddle, now its dynamic, check it out

Comment: Good one! Thanks a lot